# Does python have conditional code interpretation?

Tags: python, for-loop, conditional-statements, interpretation

I was wondering if python has something like conditional code interpretation. Something like this:

```py
x = True
if x:
    for i in range(0, 10):
else:
    for i in range(0, 100):
# ------------------------------
        print(i) # this is the code inside either one these for loop heads
```

I know I could do this:

```py
x = True
if x:
    for i in range(0, 10):
        print(i)
else:
    for i in range(0, 100):
        print(i)
```

But in my case, I have a lot of for-loop code and that wouldn't be a very good solution.

Comment: No, it does not. What you could do here though is `rng = range(10) if x else range(100)` then `for i in rng: ..`

Comment: How about a function?

Comment: Put your loop body in a function.

Comment: If you're going to use a variable anyway then just set it to `10` or `100`, and use that variable in the `range`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can always do:

```
x = True

for i in range(0,10) if x else range(0, 100):
    print(i)
```

Answer (score 1):

No, it doesn't have that syntax. You could achieve the same goal through other means, though.

For example, extract the part that varies (`10` versus `100`) from the common part (the `for in range(...)` loop):

```
limit = 10 if x else 100

for i in range(limit):
    print(i)
```

Or save one of two different ranges in a variable and loop over that:

```
numbers = range(0, 10) if x else range(0, 100)

for i in numbers:
    print(i)
```

Or extract the loop to a function that performs an arbitrary action each iteration:

```
def loop(limit, action):
    for i in range(limit):
        action(i)

loop(10 if x else 100, lambda i: print(i))
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want you could do this.

```
x = True
for i in range(0, (10 if x else 20)):
    print(i)
```

Here the if else statement work like this `result_if_true if condition else result_if_false`.

Answer (score 0):

```
if x:
    my_iter = range(0, 10)
else:
    my_iter = range(0, 100)
for i in my_iter:
     print(i)
```

Comment: Please add a bit of explanation and context around your solution.